# Merge forked repository with lastest code from master repository

Tags: git

Consider this scenario,

Repository A is the main master repository. Along the way someone decided that a customised version of A was needed for a client, so that was forked off into a separate repository B (this is not a branch).

Repository B had changes made to it but it was then left stagnated while A continued to be developed.

How would I update B with the latest version of A?

Comment: You pull from B, then you pull from A and merge in the changes, then you push to B. (Or you work in B directly and just pull A, but I assume you have the repo on some kind of server.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull and rebase the changes from A into B. Then push B to A and merge.